# MonoTouch - Detect UITableView scrolling

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a MonoTouch iPhone app which has a `UITableViewController` as it's main view controller.

I am trying to detect when the tableview is being scrolled with the code:

```
this.TableView.Scrolled += TableViewScrolled;
```

where `TableViewScrolled(object sender, EventArgs e) { }` is my method being called.
But it fails to call the `TableViewScrolled()` for some reason.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Krumelur's comment on the previous answer makes a very good point and IMO should have been an answer (not a comment).

The point is that if your set a `Delegate` (or `WeakDelegate`) to your `UITableView` then it's events won't work anymore.

**Why ?** because to implement those events MonoTouch creates it's own internal delegate type for `UIScrollView` (the parent of `UITableView`) where it overrides the methods (of the delegate) and expose them as, more *natural* (in .NET), events inside the type.

This effectively means that you cannot mix those `UITableView` events with your own delegate `UITableViewDelegate` type (since the later will override the former).

Answer (score 15):

My answer is *not actually only about the scrolling*, but because of the fact that I've spent *quite an hour* fighting with a problem caused by the scrolling event, I've decided to write answer here.

So, the problem for me was that after subscribing to:

```
this.myTableView.Scrolled += (sender, args) =>
  {
      ...
  };
```

my overriden methods of inherited from UITableViewDataSource class:

```
    public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, int section)
    public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
```

**stopped working (became not called)**. Which was... obviously, pretty unexpected!

So, I just **had to override**

```
    public override void Scrolled(UIScrollView scrollView)
```

in the same datasource delegate **instead of subscribing** to existent event on table view.

I hope, someone won't get into such trouble!

Comment: Hi I've the same kind of problem with a DialogViewController (from Monotouch MTD). In my case, as soon I start handling the scrolled event, all the tapped event on my cells stop working. As the UITableViewDataSource is dynamically created by the framework, do you know how I can override the Scrolled method instead of handling the event.

Comment: What's about implementing (overriding) your own datasource? Another option is to handle (if needed) all the events directly from Window class.

Comment: yeah, delegate, scrolled, events, properties. Meh. DataSources also prevent the event at View and Delegate from working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Read this documentation: [UIScrollViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html)

**You can use:**

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {


}
```

or

```
- (void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {


}
```

Good luck,
Nathan

Comment: Those are the methods that are mapped in MonoTouch to UITableView.Scrolled; What was why I was thinking this.TableView.Scrolled += TableViewScrolled; should do the trick. But no go. :-)

Comment: Are you using the delegate? If you do, the callbacks don't work. If you use the callbacks, the delegate doesn't work. It's either or.

Comment: @Nathan This is a question about Xamarin, where it's called Scrolled().